# I can not properly re scale <canvas> with width and height attributes

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

I'm using `Charts.js` library and my `<canvas>` element is acting strangely when i try to re scale it by changing it's `width` and `height` attributes

I'm definitely missing something , keep in mind that i capture the whole window

here are some examples:

- **width=400 , height=100**

[image]

- **width="100" height="100"**

[image]

- **width="10" height="20"**

[image]

- **width="400" height="50"**

[image]

**Try it here** , this is supposed to be a `10x10` square (pretty small right?)

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script> 
<canvas id="myChart" width="10" height="10"></canvas>
```

Why can't i make it a `100x100` square? and **not** be placed in the whole browser?do i need a `placeholder` for this?

Here is the [playground](http://tpcg.io/oyZzdw) that makes a graph non-resizable as you might notice in the `desktop` view although the `mobile` view is perfect

- Desktop View

[image]

- Mobile View

[image]

**Note:**

When `<div>` is not included and `<canvas>` has not `attributes` in browser it's huge , and on mobile resolution is perfect. If you apply `width` and `height` to `<div>` which contains `<canvas>` you can resize it but on mobile will be stretched.

**Edit:** added code snippet

**Edit2:** added code playground

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you have "reponsive" activated by default. In this case , the attributes width and height will be ignored.

The solution is to desactivate the responsive option like this :

```
 options: {
    responsive:false,
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: yes indeed , but is there any other way to keep it responsive and small at the same time?

Comment: I have another soution for you , you can encapsulate your canvas in a div <div style="  width: 30%; height: 60% ;"> and then in your options add this responsive: true,  maintainAspectRatio: false. My solution is to use "%" to keep it reponsive and control the width and height at the same time

Comment: yes that's what i'm looking for but inside a div the attributes `width` an `height` they don't act as they are supposed to , shouldn't this `<div style=" width: 30%; height: 60% ;"> ` give me a graph that the `height` is bigger than the `width` ? in fact it doesn't m it works the other way around

Comment: for example : `<div style=" width: 60%; height: 60% ;">` and `<div style=" width: 60%; height: 30% ;"> `  gives me the same `output`

Answer (score 1):

If you look at it through your console, you will notice that an extra element `div.chartjs-size-monitor` is added to the DOM right before your target canvas.

This is [done by ChartJS](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/5379) to ensure the canvas can be resized properly.

To solve the it, you simply need to

1. Move the canvas into a container element
2. Set your size at the container element.

Note that the parent element must be `display: block` (i.e., `div`).

ChartJS will change the `width` and `height` attribute of your canvas anyway, so there is no point setting it from your end.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});


/* CODE BELOW ONLY EXIST TO IMITATE BROWSER SIZE */

const wrapper = document.querySelector('#window');
const desktop = document.querySelector('#desktop');
const mobile = document.querySelector('#mobile');

desktop.addEventListener('click', resize.bind(this, 'desktop'));
mobile.addEventListener('click', resize.bind(this, 'mobile'));

function resize(size, event){
  event.preventDefault();
  wrapper.classList.remove('desktop', 'mobile')
  wrapper.classList.add(size);
}
```

```css
/* CSS HERE ONLY EXIST TO IMITATE BROWSER SIZE */

#window {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#window.desktop {
  width: 450px;
  height: 253px;
}

#window.mobile {
  width: 320px;
  height: 568px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>

<!-- Ignore these -->
<button id="desktop">Desktop</button>
<button id="mobile">Mobile</button>

<!-- #window is to imitate browser window size -->
<!-- imagine #container as the direct children of <body> -->
<div id="window" class="desktop">

  <!-- Moved all CSS to HTML as your requirement -->
  <div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative;">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: it's not working when i compile it and run it on localhost

Comment: `<div style="height:10px; width:10px">` should be the same with your `css` right?

Comment: remove the `width` and `height` attributes from `<canvas>` it's responsive and i can make it small and big  but still the square will be `x * x` based on `width` or `height`

Comment: @PhillAlexakis Saw your editted question. Is there any reason why you are not using CSS? Can you update your playground to show us what do you mean by "stretched" in mobile?

Comment: I'm trying to generate auto graphs with `chart.js` library , that's why i'm not using custom css

Comment: @PhillAlexakis please run my updated code snippet and elaborate a bit more about your requirement. From your updated playground, I am still not quite sure about your problem.

Comment: Alright it seems your solution works on snippet, basically what  i'm trying to say is that i cant resize the canvas to my desired resolution , if i change the `width` the `height` changes automatically also when i change the `height` the weird thing is that `width` stays the same. Now regarding the mobile/desktop view, i said that it acts strangely when i remove the `div` tag. If `div` has `height` and `width` attributes the browser view is fine (ignoring the resize problem i have with the attributes) but the mobile view is stretched and doesn't fit to screen. Did i make it clearer?

Comment: You should probably question , okay what do you really want to achieve? well, i i would like the  canvas to be a really small size `100x100` or `250x250` and move it around when i add some more `html` so i can place it where ever i would like. And when that page is viewed on mobile to be resized accordingly